# How to configure eclipse to only run one executable at a time?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I configure eclipse to only let me run one executable at a time? I often find that I have started an executable and forgotten about it. I'd like eclipse to stop me doing that.

Comment: For those projects/main classes you might want to run single times add a lock file which set to `deleteOnExit` and refuse to start anything useful if it is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such *configuration* for Eclipse; it goes against the fundamental concept that the IDE supports arbitrary numbers of projects and debug processes. The only options you have involve custom code, either in your application (as suggested by @Gábor Bakos in the comments above) or via a plug-in you write yourself.